# Form Not Validating when Using Anchor to Submit

Tags: javascript, validation, anchor

I'm trying to submit a form using an anchor tag.  However, the validation function doesn't seem to get triggered. I've since replaced the anchor with a submit button and it now works.  Still, I'm curious why the previous anchor link didn't work.

The code is

```
function validate() {

/* validation code here */

return status;

}

<form id="myForm" action="/response_page.php" onsubmit="return validate();" method="POST">

<!-- form elements here -->

<a href="#" class="submit_button" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Submit</a>

</form>
```

With this code, clicking the link goes straight to *response_page.php*.  But when replaced with a submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

WITHOUT changing the validate function and form tag, the validate function is called correctly. What's wrong with the anchor?

Thanks

Comment: status = true or false depending whether certain form validations were met. validation code was not included anymore as it can be any type of verification

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior.

From [the MDN on the submit function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) :

> The form's onsubmit event handler (for example, onsubmit="return
>   false;") will not be triggered when invoking this method from
>   Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be
>   invoked by HTML user agents.

If you want to validate your code in your link, just call the `validate` function explicitely :

```
<a id=subbut href="#" class="submit_button">Submit</a>
...
document.getElementById('subbut').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (validate()) document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Yes! It worked! But wouldn't the validate() function be called twice, the second time from the form's onsubmit event?

Comment: Actually the problem is with the validate function. The submit event is being called, but the validate function is being bypassed in the form's onsubmit event when submit() is called from the anchor